# Elastic consuming a lot of RAM and server CPU

Tags: elasticsearch, microservices, .net-6.0, apm, elastic-apm

Elastic APM is causing a memory leak in high data processing microservices in .net core 6 and using version 1.22.0 of Elastic.Apm.NetCoreAll and Elastic.Apm.StackExchange.Redis, thus consuming a lot of ram from the server

Has anyone experienced this and could you suggest/help how to reduce RAM usage and CPU consumption in this case?

Thanks in advance

I tried to optimize the apm performance settings as per the documentation
 `"TransactionSampleRate": 0.2 "StackTraceLimit": 0, "SpanStackTraceMinDuration": "10ms", "CaptureHeaders": false, "MetricsInterval": "1s", "Enabled": true`
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/performance-tuning.html#performance-tuning-stack-traces

But there was no significant improvement

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue? We're facing a similar issue with our microservices running in K8S after implementing APM. I found this post in Elastic (also from you), but there is no resolution before closing the topic: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-consuming-a-lot-of-server-ram-and-cpu/346246